# AT+ Command to delete "[sms dilivery] status reports"?

Tags: sms, serial-port, modem, at-command

I'm trying to delete 'status reports' in the device using the following code-list:

```
AT
 : OK
AT+CMGF=1
 : OK
AT+CPMS="SR"
 : +CPMS: 4,100,0,45,4,100
AT+CMGD=50
 : ERROR
```

Note: there is a 'status report' available at the index:50.

Could you tell me what causes this error? 
Thanks.

Comment: The output of the +CPMS says that there are 4 messages.  Try listing them with AT+CMGL="ALL"

Comment: @dbasnett, thanks for the reply. Actually `AT+CMGL="ALL"` too produces `ERROR`. But `AT+CMGR=50` reads the correct **status report** without an error.

Comment: And `+CMGD` , `+CMGL` commands are failing only for **status reports**. They work perfectly fine when it comes to other messages (stored in: SM, ME or MT)

Comment: Try to find the AT commands for your specific phone.  As with many standards, they aren't very standard.

Answer (score 0):

According to "ETSI TS 100 585", 
0: "REC UNREAD"
1: "REC READ"
2: "STO UNSENT"
3: "STO SENT"
4: "ALL"

so maybe you can try "AT+CMGL=4" to see if it works. 
If it works, you can use "at+cmgd=index" to delete the SMS you want

Comment: thanks @user2861965, but like I said `AT+CMGL=50` works while  `AT+CMGD=50` fails.

Comment: Hi, dan. you mean AT+CMGL=50 or AT+CMGR=50?  What is your response when you use AT+CMGL=50?

Comment: Hi @user2861965, I've made a mistake it has to be, both `+CMGL` and `+CMGD` are **failing** (but `+CMGR` is working). See what I'm trying to achieve here is to delete **Status Reports**. Thanks.

Comment: What's your response of "AT+CMGR=50"? and also "AT+CMPS?"